# Variable inside regular expression in Python's series.str.contains framework

Tags: python, regex, string, dataframe, contains

I want to control/edit elements of a regex as variables before running the regex.
In the regex I am using, I want to find the rows in a data frame containing 2 words separated by a maximum of 3 words.

This code identifies word1 and word2, using the regex without outside variables:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['some text here', 'some text there', 'word1 some more text word2']})
result = df['a'].str.contains(r"\b(?:word1\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?word2|word2\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?word1)\b") 

print(result)
0    False
1    False
2    True
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

What I want is to reach the same result but being able to control word1, word2 and the value 3  outside the regex.

Here is my failed attempt to define variables outside the regex, adapting from answers to similar questions here on stackoverflow:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

Var1 = "word1"
Var2 = "word2"
Var3 = "3"


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['some text here', 'some text there', 'word1 some more text word2']})
result = df['a'].str.contains(r"\b(?:{Var1}\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,{Var3}}?{Var2}|{Var2}\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,{Var3}}?{Var1})\b") 
   
print(result)
0    False
1    False
2    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

Similarly this one also fails:

```
result = df['a'].str.contains(r"\b(?:"+Var1+"\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,"+Var3+"}?"+Var2+"|"+Var2+"\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,"+Var3+"}?"+Var1+")\b")
```

Is there a simple way to adapt the regex to read Var1 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your raw string with `f-strings` ([New in version 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals)), but first you have to escape the curly braces on regex quantifiers.

> The parts of the string outside curly braces are treated literally, except that any doubled curly braces '{{' or '}}' are replaced with the corresponding single curly brace. A single opening curly bracket '{' marks a replacement field, which starts with a Python expression...

```py
rf"\b(?:{Var1}\W+(?:\w+\W+){{0,{Var3}}}?{Var2}|{Var2}\W+(?:\w+\W+){{0,{Var3}}}?{Var1})\b"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!